# How to raise or return 405 method not allowed in Django

Tags: python, django, exception

I want to raise or return a 405 Method not allowed but I cannot find how. Like in Flask you could do abort(405). Is there anyway to raise or return a Django 405 exception.

Comment: This could be helpful for you: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/ There is also the possibility to create a custom exception handler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer. You could use what Alex has said. But you can also use the  HttpResponseNotAllowed and click [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseNotAllowed) for the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseNotAllowed). If you want to return a custom one just do the following: `return render(request, "Error Pages/405.html", status=405)`. Notice the status, that is what will tell the browser about the code that is being returned.